# How to print table with one header

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
someFile = open("komad_namestaja.txt", "r")

for linija in someFile.readlines():
    code, name, color, quantity, price, category = linija.split("|")

    print("---------------------------------------------------------------------+")
    print("Code   |Name         |Color      |Quantity|Price       |category   |")    #Header     print("-------+-------------+-----------+--------+-----------+-------------+")
    print("{0:8.8}|{1:14.14}|{2:10.10}|{3:8.8}|{4:11.11}|{5:13.6}|".format(code, name, color, quantity, price, category))
```

This is my code for making table of information from file.
Problem is, code print for every line in file new header.
What am doing wrong?

Comment: You want your 1st and 2nd print above the for loop and the 3rd print inside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move your header before your loop, and print info inside the loop:

```
someFile = open("komad_namestaja.txt", "r")

print("-------------------------------------------------------------------+")
print("Code   |Name         |Color      |Quantity|Price       |category   |")       
print("-------+-------------+-----------+--------+------------+-----------+")

for linija in someFile.readlines():
    code, name, color, quantity, price, category = linija.split("|")
    print("{0:8.8}|{1:14.14}|{2:10.10}|{3:8.8}|{4:11.11}|{5:13.6}|".format(code, name, color, quantity, price, category))
```

Comment: If this is the answer you are looking for, thanking is not necessary. Instead you can mark the answer as accepted. Happy coding !